# MARS model using library earth in R: Why the both "cv_mars" and "mars1" are producing the same results?

Tags: r, database, regression, prediction

I used

```
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
      degree = 1:10, 
      nprune = seq(2, 1000, length.out = 100) %>% floor()
    )
head(hyper_grid)
```

for tuning the MARS model

```
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
    cv_mars <- train(
      x = subset(train, select = -Rm),
      y = train[,1],
      method = "earth",
      metric = "RMSE",
      trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
      tuneGrid = hyper_grid)
```

used to train the MARS model with earth library in R and then

```
# View RMSE R2 MAE #
    cv_mars$results %>%
      filter(nprune == cv_mars$bestTune$nprune, degree == cv_mars$bestTune$degree)
```

used to evaluate the performance matrices. HOWEVER, I am looking for

**1. Why both models ("cv_mars" and "mars1") produced the same results? What is missing here? Even used another hyper_grid as**

```
`hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
  degree = 1:3, 
  nprune = seq(2, 100, length.out = 10) %>% floor()
)
head(hyper_grid)`
```

the data is as:

```
    > dput(train)
structure(list(Rm = c(0, 86.7072111207646, 86.2148856067188, 
85.0275123081378, 98.9574283231972, 99.9710396756444, 99.8841587025775, 
99.7393570807993, 99.9710396756444, 55.4133333333333, 54.5066666666667, 
56.8533333333333, 99.68, 99.8133333333333, 99.92, 99.8933333333333, 
99.8666666666667, 99.8666666666667, 99.9466666666667, 99.8666666666667, 
99.84, 99.5675675675676, 99.2972972972973, 99.4324324324324, 
99.5675675675676, 99.5135135135135, 99.4864864864865, 99.5405405405405, 
99.8108108108108, 99.7837837837838, 99.8648648648649, 99.8648648648649, 
99.8648648648649, 99.7837837837838, 99.8918918918919, 99.8378378378378, 
99.2432432432432, 96.3243243243243, 96.2432432432432, 97.1891891891892, 
99.8477157360406, 99.7457627118644, 99.9717514124294, 99.8870056497175, 
99.7933884297521, 99.2492492492492, 99.6996996996997, 99.7597597597598, 
98.2548701298701, 96.25, 96.6764705882353, 96.889705882353, 79.9844236760125, 
51.2048192771084, 51.3052208835341, 38.4538152610442, 40.9037558685446, 
40.5587668593449, 30.3468208092486, 28.9980732177264, 30.7563025210084, 
26.551724137931, 24.7126436781609, 28.5057471264368), IC = c(50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 25, 50, 50, 50, 75, 100, 100, 100, 
150, 200, 200, 200, 250, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1250, 1250, 1250, 
1500, 2000, 2000, 2000), Dose = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 10, 10, 10, 
15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), CT = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 5, 5, 5, 15, 30, 30, 30, 60, 90, 90, 90, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120), pH = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 12, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Na = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

    > dput(test)
structure(list(Rm = c(0, 0, 99.5945554590211, 99.1891109180423, 
99.9420793512887, 99.98, 99.76, 99.7066666666667, 99.8933333333333, 
99.9733333333333, 99.68, 99.5733333333334, 99.6216216216216, 
99.6216216216216, 99.8378378378378, 99.7567567567567, 99.8918918918919, 
99.8648648648649, 99.1351351351351, 99.1621621621622, 99.5431472081218, 
99.6954314720812, 99.5867768595041, 99.8140495867768, 97.4512987012987, 
98.2467532467532, 78.3878504672897, 79.9065420560748, 41.0211267605634, 
41.1971830985916, 19.4117647058824, 30.1680672268908), IC = c(50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 25, 25, 75, 75, 150, 150, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 1500, 
1500), Dose = c(0, 0, 5, 5, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10), CT = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 15, 15, 60, 60, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120), pH = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Na = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the predicted value by the MARS model you can use the following code

```
#For prediction of training data
(mars_cal <- predict(cv_mars, newdata = dataTrain))
#For prediction of testing data
(mars_val <- predict(cv_mars, newdata = dataTest))
```

As you have not provided any data, I have provided a general code.

Comment: thank you so much again for your generous support, however, this could have solved successfully but now another issue is that the basic MARS model prediction and the tuned one are producing the same result how?

Comment: the basic Mars model code used:                            mars1 <- earth(Rm ~ ., data = train); so for both cases the results are the same; is there something I missed, please point out and suggest by your esteems guidance.

Comment: Even I used different hyper_grid as:                 hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
degree = 1:3, 
  nprune = seq(2, 100, length.out = 10) %>% floor()
)
head(hyper_grid); BUT the results are still the same, please lightup here, best regards!

Comment: Data is added to the above question as dput(train) and dput(test). many thanks!